# From Azure AD Token to Microsoft Graph Token in Next-Auth (react)

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, next-auth

Hi Stackoverflow community,
this is my first question here after not finding a solution to my problem.

To begin with, we are having an app registration on azure to our Azure Active Directory and configured our react-next-js project to authenticate with it.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      name: 'Azure Active Directory',
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID ?? 'undefined',
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? 'undefined',
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'api://ownscope/general openid profile email user.read ',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'light',
  },
  callbacks: {
    /**
     * Controls
     * @param param{account, profile, user}
     * @returns True iff user is allowed to sign in
     */
    
    async signIn()
    {
      return true
    },
    // user, profile
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.access_token = account.access_token;
        try {
          const graphClient = getGraphClient(
            {access_token: account.access_token} as { access_token: string }
          )
          token.graphdata = await graphClient.api('/me').get()
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Failed to load MS Graph data')
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
      return token
    },
    // , user
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Transform graphdata to user model
      session.userdata = ToUser(token.graphdata)
      return session
    },
  },
  events: {
    async signIn(message) {
      console.log(
        'Logged in successfully: %s',
        JSON.stringify(message.user.name)
      )
    },
    async session(message) {
      console.log(
        'Session active: %s',
        JSON.stringify(message?.session?.user?.name)
      )
    },
  },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Which does work fine, the login screen is coming up and we can login with our user. The returned access_token is good and does have the 'aud' from our app registration:
[AAD_Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjMSD.png)

We need this token to access our API which is protected with this app registration (Azure API Management). And this works too.

But as you can see in our next-auth code, we want to get further user informations from Microsoft Graph Endpoint (The used graph client is microsoft/microsoft-graph-client). We added the scopes for profile and user.read in our authentication request.
And I tried to access the Graph endpoint with postman too. Which get's the response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-08-31T13:39:54",
            "request-id": "9e161f21-3eca-4b6e-8678-ab1edd803e13",
            "client-request-id": "9e161f21-3eca-4b6e-8678-ab1edd803e13"
        }
    }
}
```

Which does make sense since the checked audience is from our AAD and not the expected Microsoft Graph auth.
Removing our own scope from the request results in a Microsoft graph access token, but we can't access our API with it:
[Graph Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSb6N.png)

How can we get a valid Microsoft Graph token in next-auth after successfully login into our AAD account?

Comment: if you're calling Graph from your app/API, you may want to look at the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to exchange your first token for a Graph token.

Comment: What was your solution to this MrAnderson?